# Get current tranform value before applying the new one without javascript

Tags: css, inheritance, transform, css-variables

Is there any way to apply the same css var in a consecutive way? Or to get the current css property value and then appending a new one? I need this to apply multiple transforms on some nested elements.

Working example needs 2 separate var for parent and child

```html
<style>
  p {
    transform: scale(var(--scale, 1)) scale(var(--parentScale, 1)) ;
  }
</style>
<div style="--parentScale: 0.8">
   <p style="--scale: -1;">Hello</p>
 </div>
```

But I would like to write it like this (not working unfortunately inner --scale gets replaced by the parent --scale leaving the 'Hello' unsized)

```html
<style>
  p {
    transform: scale(var(--scale, 1));
  }
</style>
<div style="--scale: 0.8">
  <p style="--scale: -1;">Hello</p>
</div>
```

Is there any workaround for this? If possibile without js

Comment: Although you set a --scale variable in the div you never use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A --scale variable is defined in the div but it's never used on the div.

This snippet sets both div and p to have a transform *each with its relevant `--scale`*

```css
div,
p {
  transform: scale(var(--scale, 1));
}
```

```html
<div style="--scale: 0.8">
  <p style="--scale: -1;">Hello</p>
</div>
```

UPDATE: there is a clarification from the comments that it's each individual child, not the parent div, that needs to have that 0.8 scaling.

This snippet therefore introduces a second variable, --childscale, which is initially set to 1 and is combined with the --scale. Any div that does not set it is unaffected. For the div where you are looking for the flipping over -childscale is set to -1.

```css
p {
  transform: scale(calc(var(--scale) * var(--childscale)), 1);
}
```

```html
<div style="--scale: 0.8; --childscale: 1;">
  <p style="--childscale: -1;">Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! i have to admit this is a bit confusing but I'm trying to apply the transform on the children of the div, not directly on the div itself, this example is more clear and it shows that only one of the 2 children get scaled down, not both. They're not merging their transforms: https://jsfiddle.net/cyhkxqvp/2/

Comment: I think these examples will show you in a more visual way why I want to apply the scale on the children and not the parent itself: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72303162/apply-ccs-vars-in-a-consecutive-way-without-replacing-the-current-value-concate

Comment: You are overriding the --scale that is set in the parent when you set one which has the same name in a child.

Comment: You are going to need to name two variables, not just one. Is that a problem?

Comment: Yes unfortunately it will be since I have multiple nested elements and creating a css var for each child and parent doesn't seem a really good idea. Here's a fiddle with problem on multiple nested elements: https://jsfiddle.net/8d1kbt5v/

Comment: I think i'm really getting close to the solution here: https://jsfiddle.net/ab0vzwr2/ but it only uses the div tag, I need that to work with the use and path tag, thinking maybe a workaround would be wrapping element into a g, and then do this trick of the 2 vars on multiple nested g. Wow seems like i'm working at some NASA stuff lol. Will do some testing thanks for your great input anyway!